# Cambiarle el color a un botón cuando en un input hay un valor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola buenas tardes intento realizar un código que cambie el color de un botón cuando en un input hay un valor = 1 el botón este de un color rojo y cuando el input tenga un valor de 0 este de color verde, la verdad no se como se hace.

```html
<input type="text" name="asunto" value="1" ><br>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-16" style='width:200px; height:36px' id="bad" name="bad">
Tarde libre por cumpleaños</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//Ejecutamos la funcion al cargar
$(function() {
  check();

//funcion que se ejecuta al cambiar valor del input
  $("#valor").keyup(function() {
    check();
  });
});

//valida el color
function check() {
  var opcion = $("#valor").val();

  if (opcion == 1) {
    $("#bad").css("background-color", "red");
  } else if (opcion == 0) {
    $("#bad").css("background-color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#bad").css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="asunto" value="1" id="valor"><br>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-16" style='width:200px; height:36px' id="bad" name="bad">
Tarde libre por cumpleaños</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

con jQuery podrías hacer lo siguiente, capturando el evento `input`, chequeas cual es el valor que posee el `input`, en caso de ser `0` asigno la clase `.cero`, en caso de ser `1` `.uno` y si no es ninguno de los dos, `.otro`

```js
$('input').on('input',function()
{  

  var btn = $('#bad');
  
  btn.removeClass('uno');
  btn.removeClass('cero');
  btn.removeClass('otro');
  
  switch($(this).val()) {
    case '0':
        btn.addClass('cero');
        break;
    case '1':
        btn.addClass('uno');
        break;
    default:
       btn.addClass('otro');
        break;
}
  
});
```

```css
button
{
  color: white;
}
button.uno
{
  background-color:red;  
}
button.cero
{
  background-color: green;  
}
button.otro
{
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="asunto" ><br>


<button id="bad" name="bad" class="otro">
Tarde libre por cumpleaños</button>
```

Espero que sea lo que andabas buscando!

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacerlo con **keyup** para obtener el valor del input al escrivir algo asi :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#asunto").keyup(function(){

  var valor=$(this).val();
  
  if(valor >0){
  $("#bad").css("background","green")
  }else{
  $("#bad").css("background","none")
  }
})

})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="asunto" value="0" id="asunto"><br>


<button type="submit" class=""  id="bad" name="bad">
Tarde libre por cumpleaños</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Realice un pequeño código. Cuando le des click al botón si el campo posee el valor **1** el color del botón cambiará, espero que te sirva:

```js
$("#cambiar").click((e) => {

  let valorInput = parseInt($("#campoColor").val().trim());
  
  if(valorInput === 1){
    $(e.target).addClass("conColor");
  }else{
    $(e.target).removeClass("conColor");
  }

});
```

```css
.conColor{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="" id="campoColor"><button id="cambiar">Cambiar color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma seria con javascript

```js
function cambiar() {
  var contenido = document.getElementsById("asunto")[0].value;

  if(contenido == 0 ){
   document.getElementById("#bad").style.backgroundColor="green";
  }
  else if(contenido == 1 ){
   document.getElementById("#bad").style.backgroundColor="red";
  }
  else{
   alert('El valor no es reconocido, intente de nuevo');
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="asunto" name="asunto" onchange="cambiar()"><br>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-16" style='width:200px; height:36px' id="bad" name="bad">
Tarde libre por cumpleaños</button>
```

Con `jQuery` lo puedes hacer mucho mas facil de esta forma
        function cambiar() {
            var contenido = $("#asunto").val().trim();

```
        if(contenido == 0 ){
            $("#bad").css('background', 'green');
        }
        else if(contenido == 1 ){
            $("#bad").css('background', 'red');
        }
        else{
            alert('El valor no es reconocido, intente de nuevo');
        }
    }
```

recuerda importar la libreria si lo usasa asi

Answer (score 1):

Mira lo que puedes hacer es meter en una variable tu input y tu button, y con el método `onkeydown` de HTML para llamar tu función cada vez que tecleas un valor y dependiendo el valor cambiamos los estilos accediendo a los métodos de tu elemento HTML que guardamos previamente para cambiar la propiedad del background

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="asunto" value="1" id="Myinput" onkeydown="RevisarValor()"><br>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-16" style='width:200px; height:36px' id="bad" name="bad" >
Tarde libre por cumpleaños</button>
```

Ten en cuenta que pido el valor del DOM cada vez que ejecuto la función

JS:

```
var MiBoton = document.getElementById('bad');
function RevisarValor(){
var ValorInput = document.getElementById('Myinput').value;
  console.log("Valor input = ",ValorInput);
  if(ValorInput == 0){
    MiBoton.style.background = "green";
  }else if(ValorInput == 1){
    MiBoton.style.background = "red";
  }
}
```

Veo que igual usas Bootstrap, asi que puedes cambiar el `MiBoton.style.background = "red"` por un `MiBoton.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger")` o `success` para el verde, Espero haber contestado tu duda.